# angular factory, return statement in then() promise returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I call the following factory in my controller with  `MakeBusMarkers(orderedFilteredData)`.

`Console.log(mark)` returns a valid object (called right before the return statement). 

I presume a simple answer, but what am I doing wrong?

```
.factory('MakeBusMarkers', ['busesByDepot', '$timeout', 'CamelToString', function(busesByDepot, $timeout, CamelToString){

// make leaflet map markers from filtered data

return function(orderedFilteredData){
    var mark = {};

    busesByDepot.then(function(keyMap){     
        orderedFilteredData.forEach(function(currentVal){
            mark[currentVal.num] = {
                message : '#' + currentVal.num.toString()
            }

            ...some additional code here...

        console.log(mark);
        return mark;
    });
}

}])
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `return` before `busesByDepot.then(...)` ?

Comment: How you calling busesByDepot.Will u please share it

Answer (score 0):

Correct,

The factory then returns a promise object. Thank you.

```
.factory('MakeBusMarkers', ['busesByDepot', '$timeout', 'CamelToString', function(busesByDepot, $timeout, CamelToString){

// make leaflet map markers from filtered data

return function(orderedFilteredData){
var mark = {};

return busesByDepot.then(function(keyMap){     
    orderedFilteredData.forEach(function(currentVal){
        mark[currentVal.num] = {
            message : '#' + currentVal.num.toString()
        }

        ...some additional code here...

    console.log(mark);
    return mark;
});
}

}])
```